# How can you set the swagger path in servicestack?

Tags: servicestack

By default the documentation generated by swagger sits at /swagger-ui is there a simple mechanism to change this path to something more user defined such as /documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The `/swagger-ui/` and `/swagger-ui-bootstrap/` paths are hard-coded to match the `\swagger-ui` and `\swagger-ui-bootstrap` folders and cannot be changed.

You could create a new Service or filter and redirect to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the actual folder path from /swagger-ui/ to /documentation/. (make sure to search for the old swagger-ui string in the rest of the project and update the references where it makes sense, i think just in the index.html file)

Optionally, when registering your metadata plugins(if enabled) - you may want to update the Swagger link on the metadata page, which can be done by adding a link to the metadata swagger plugin

via appHost.GetPlugin()
    .AddPluginLink("documentation/", "Swagger UI");